# Is it possible to use a PCL library from powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, automation, integration, portable-class-library

I developed a cross-platform SDK in C#, therefore I have this PCL libraries with profiles including .Net45 and .Net40.

To implement an automation scriptable tool, I was thinking to reference the library from some scripting language like powershell (any other/better option?) but not sure how to do that or if it is possible at all? Especially considering that all the SDK calls are asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason why this isnt possible. Just include the dll using [Add-Type](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwjPgYTWtuXIAhWE2ywKHeCNCaA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fhh849914.aspx&usg=AFQjCNE-P6hEbq9UOgVXyeBksl0Gy3S-lA&sig2=MawHnBYSq7Oj6hbAZdqwxg) and use it.